# if statement query user id in etc/passwd?

Tags: bash, text-processing, users, etc, passwd

Using bash I am trying to query `/etc/passwd` for any users with an id over 1000.  If they exist do something, else do something else.  I'm stumped. Any help is appreciated.

```
if [ "$(id -u)" -gt "1000" </etc/passwd]; then
    do something
else
    do something else
fi
```

Comment: Does this have to be in bash (shell)?

Comment: yes, sorry. using bash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
if grep -E '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]{4}' /etc/passwd | grep -Evq '^[^:]*:[^:]*:1000:'
```

The first `grep` searches `passwd` for lines with a uid of four or more
digits. The second `grep` filters out the line with uid 1000. The exit
status will be 0 if any lines remain, 1 if not.

Comment: i get syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: You have to follow it with a `then` line, etc.

Comment: I forgot; make the second grep `-Evq` to suppress its output.

Comment: From the look of it, this looks for UID fields which are at least 4 characters long, which works here but isn't very useful if the cutoff value is something other than a power of ten. Also the results may be confusing if some of the numbers get leading zeroes for some reason.

Comment: If you use YP/NIS or LDAP, then parse the output of `getent passwd` instead of the `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: @ilkkachu True, good point. I don’t know a good way to compare the numbers numerically using standard tools, do you? Perhaps a small `awk` script or such.

Answer (score 16):

To do that in a `bash` loop, I suggest using `read` and `IFS` like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS=':' read -r user passwd uid gid comment home shell;  do
    if [ "$uid" -gt 1000 ] ; then
        echo GT $user
    else
        echo LT $user
    fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: tried that but it outputs all users LT and GT

Comment: It outputs *some* users as LT, and the rest as GT.  Which is what I thought you needed.

Comment: i only want to check etc/password to see if any UIDs greater than 1000 exist and do something if true, do something else if false..

Comment: The key words in your comment is *if any*, the question said *for* and *they*.  The plural *they* indicated to me that you intended to process each user.  But three other answers here did not read it that way, so....

Answer (score 14):

Instead of reading `/etc/passwd` directly, you should use `getent passwd`, that will also work if some of your users are saved in something like LDAP or such. `awk` should be well-suited for the colon-separated output format.

This would print the usernames of all users with UID > 1000:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 > 1000 {print $1}'
```

And this would just print `found` if at least one such is found:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 > 1000 {print "found"; exit}'
```

Comment: how would i use this with an if statement though? if $3 > 1000, do something

Comment: I modified this a bit, because the first desktop user equals 1000, and there are other types of users like "nobody", so we also need an upper limit (which I've just arbitrarily set to 2000): `getent passwd | awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $3 < 2000 {print $1}'`

Comment: @benjaoming, err, yes, `>= 1000` would indeed seem to make sense. The question had `> 1000` for some reason though. `nobody` seems to be commonly `6553x` or `3276x`, so you can probably raise that upper limit a bit.

Answer (score 4):

This construct doesn't make much sense:

```
"$(id -u)" -gt "1000" </etc/passwd
```

The `id` command works regardless of the input redirection. The redirection doesn't make sense here anyhow.

You can use this pipeline in your test comparison. It will show you the highest user id on the machine:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $3}' | sort -n | tail -n1
```

You may want to tweak it for some systems as there may be the `nobody` user with UID `65534` present.

Answer (score 1):

Using Tom's code this worked for me..

```
#!/bin/sh
if grep -E '^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]{4}' /etc/passwd | grep -Evq '^[^:]*:[^:]*:1000:'
then 
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "not exists"
fi
```

Comment: i created a user mrBlonde:x:1001:1001::/home/mrBlonde:/bin/bash. when i run the code it says exists, when i delete the user, it says not exists. L)