# How to retrieve information of a user?

Tags: sudo, users, group

After running below commands,

```
[root@u87 ~]# getent group somegroup
somegroup:*:2441:someuser
[root@u87 ~]#
[root@u87 ~]#
[root@u87 ~]# cat /etc/group | grep somegroup
[root@u87 ~]# 
[root@u87 ~]# cat /etc/passwd | grep someuser
[root@u87 ~]#
[root@u87 ~]# getent passwd | grep someuser
[root@u87 ~]# 
[root@u87 ~]#
[root@u87 ~]# sudo su - someuser
su: user someuser does not exist
[root@u87 ~]#
[root@u87 ~]#
[root@u87 ~]# cat /etc/system-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo
```

---

I would like to know,

1) How to retrieve information about `someuser`? basically information like uid

2) Why `sudo su - someuser` does not work? despite `someuser` exist in some DB

Comment: Do you have a user named `someuser`?  What does `getent passwd someuser` say?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353975/117549

Comment: @AndyDalton `getent passwd someuser` gives no output but why `getent group somegroup` has member user `someuser`  as mentioned in `somegroup:*:2441:someuser`?

Comment: Was the group database not updated when the user was removed from the system? Do you have historical records showing that this user actually existed at some point in time?